# Swapfile is not created after reboot using cloud-init

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, cloud-init

## My configuration

I'm trying to deploy a virtual machine in Azure using a Oracle Linux image (version 8.4, generation 2). We change the mount point of the Azure temporary disk (ephemeral0) to `/mnt/resource`. In addition I create a swapfile on the temporary disk. I'm using the following custom cloud-init script during deployment:

```
#cloud-config
datasource_list: [ Azure ]
mounts:
- [ ephemeral0, /mnt/resource, auto, "defaults,nofail,x-systemd.requires=cloud-init.service" ]
mount_default_fields: [ None, None, "auto", "defaults,nofail", "0", "2" ]
swap:
  filename: /mnt/resource/swap.img
  size: "auto" # or size in bytes
  max_size: 17179869184 # 16GB
```

On the first boot right after VM creation everything (ephemeral0 and swap) is working as expected.
If I take a look in `/var/log/cloud-init.log` you can see the following entries:

```
[root@test01 ~]# cat /var/log/cloud-init.log | grep swap
2021-08-16 08:19:29,814 - cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to determine the real name of swap
2021-08-16 08:19:29,814 - cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: changed default device swap => None
2021-08-16 08:19:29,814 - cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: Ignoring nonexistent default named mount swap
2021-08-16 08:19:29,815 - cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: suggest 4096.0 MB swap for 7672.03125 MB memory with '17018.25390625 MB' disk given max=None [max=4254.5634765625 MB]'
2021-08-16 08:19:29,815 - cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: Creating swapfile in '/mnt/resource/swap.img' on fstype 'xfs' using 'fallocate'
2021-08-16 08:19:29,815 - subp.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['fallocate', '-l', '4096M', '/mnt/resource/swap.img'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
2021-08-16 08:19:29,849 - subp.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['mkswap', '/mnt/resource/swap.img'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
2021-08-16 08:19:29,887 - util.py[DEBUG]: Setting up swap file took 0.072 seconds
2021-08-16 08:19:29,893 - cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: Changes to fstab: ['+ /dev/disk/cloud/azure_resource-part1 /mnt/resource auto defaults,nofail,x-systemd.requires=cloud-init.service,comment=cloudconfig 0 2', '+ /mnt/resource/swap.img none swap sw,comment=cloudconfig 0 0']
2021-08-16 08:19:29,893 - subp.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['swapon', '-a'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
2021-08-16 08:19:29,929 - cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: Activate mounts: PASS:swapon -a
```

As you can see cloud-init suggests 4096 MB as swapsize.

In `/etc/fstab` the following entries are added:

```
/dev/disk/cloud/azure_resource-part1    /mnt/resource   auto    defaults,nofail,x-systemd.requires=cloud-init.service,comment=cloudconfig       0       2
/mnt/resource/swap.img  none    swap    sw,comment=cloudconfig  0       0
```

Also `swapon -s` states that swap is configured corretly:

```
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/mnt/resource/swap.img                  file            4194300 0       -2
```

## The Problem

Now if I deallocate the virtual machine and start it again the temporary disk is deleted and recreated as expected. It is mounted again under `/mnt/resource` but swap is not created any longer. `/var/log/cloud-init.log` states:

```
2021-08-16 08:29:33,331 - cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to determine the real name of swap
2021-08-16 08:29:33,331 - cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: changed default device swap => None
2021-08-16 08:29:33,331 - cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: Ignoring nonexistent default named mount swap
2021-08-16 08:29:33,331 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /proc/swaps (quiet=False)
2021-08-16 08:29:33,331 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 37 bytes from /proc/swaps
2021-08-16 08:29:33,331 - cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: swap file /mnt/resource/swap.img exists, but not in /proc/swaps
2021-08-16 08:29:33,332 - cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: suggest 0.0 MB swap for 7672.03125 MB memory with '12889.515625 MB' disk given max=None [max=3222.37890625 MB]'
2021-08-16 08:29:33,332 - cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: Not creating swap: suggested size was 0
2021-08-16 08:29:33,337 - cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: Changes to fstab: ['- /mnt/resource/swap.img none swap sw,comment=cloudconfig 0 0']
```

For my understanding the `cc_mounts` module of cloud-init suggests a swapsize of 0 MB because it determines that the temporary disk has only about 12 GB space left. This seems to be wrong since (a) the disk is empty due to deallocating and (b) `df -h` states it has about 15 GB available:

```
[root@test01 ~]# df -h /mnt/resource/
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1        16G   45M   15G   1% /mnt/resource
```

Am I missing something here? Can anybody explain why cloud-init behaves like this and how to create a swapfile properly for every reboot?

Answer (score 0):

•   Your problem is occurred from a misconfiguration that causes Azure Linux Agent and the cloud init agent to try to configure the swap file. When cloud-init is responsible for provisioning, the swap file must be configured by cloud-init to enable only one agent (either cloud-init or waagent) for provisioning. This issue can be intermittent because of the timing of when the waagent daemons start.

•   You can fix this problem by disabling the disk formatting and then swapping the configuration within the waagent configuration file, i.e., /etc/waagent.conf and ensuring that the azure linux agent is not mounting the ephemeral disk as this should be handled by the cloud-init agent. For this purpose, set the parameters as below: -

#vi /etc/waagent.conf

#Mount point for the resource disk

```
ResourceDisk.MountPoint=/mnt
```

#Create and use swapfile on resource disk

```
ResourceDisk.EnableSwap=n
```

#Size of the swapfile

```
ResourceDisk.SwapSizeMB=0
```

•   Restart the Azure Linux agent and ensure that the VM is configured to create a swap file through cloud init. Also, add the below script to ‘/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot’ and making the file executable by using the ‘# chmod +x create_swapfile.sh’ command: -

```
#!/bin/sh

 if [ ! -f '/mnt/swapfile' ]; then

 fallocate --length 2GiB /mnt/swapfile

 chmod 600 /mnt/swapfile

 mkswap /mnt/swapfile

 swapon /mnt/swapfile

 swapon -a

 else

 swapon /mnt/swapfile; fi
```

•   Once done, stop and start the VM and check for swap enablement. Below is its example. Also, compare the logs from /var/log/waagent.log and /var/log/cloud-init.log for reboot timeframe. To avoid this situation completely, deploy the VM by using the swap configuration custom data during provisioning.

Please find the below documentation for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/swap-file-not-recreated-linux-vm-restart

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/update-linux-agent

Thanking you,